How to report user is locked to OpenId client?
I have an OIDC Identity Server in ASP.NET, and there is a client (also in ASP.NET) connecting to it for authorization using the client credentials flow.
When a user tries to log in and enters the wrong password a configured number of times, their account gets locked. The client wants to record some logs when this happens, including details like the username, lockout duration (e.g., locked for X minutes), and the time the lockout occurred (e.g., Y time offset).
What is the best way to communicate this information to the client?
I was considering sending claims or parameters to the client since we know the return URL.
What is the recommended approach to handle this?

it's probably best practice not to provide feedback to locked clients and instead have the client refer them to a support channel when blocked

When you say client it feels like you are referring to a customer organization rather than an application. You might clarify that and explain the setup. You cannot issue tokens when user authentication fails.
In OAuth, the authorization server (AS) - or OIDC provider if you prefer - should deal with security auditing and informing people. Here are a few usage patterns that are common in cloud native deployments. You might look into your provider's support for them.
AUDIT LOGS
Instances of the AS write audit logs which you aggregate and provide to interested people for them to query. Is this the best fit for your use case?
select * from login_attempts where ...

SECURITY EVENTS
The AS allows you to subscribe to events like lockouts and perform custom actions like notifying people. You might also be able to use logging events to detect occurrences and run custom actions.
METRICS
The AS provides custom metrics at an internal endpoint that a monitoring system like Prometheus queries and records data as a time series. If a metric like login_lockout_rate or login_failure_rate exceeds a threshold you might raise people alerts like emails.
